# Sumar las filas de un dataframe de pandas agrupando por las últimas n fechas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Tengo un dataframe de pandas que luce así:

| Ac | Type | Id | Date | Value | Pe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2017-12-31 | 5 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2018-03-31 | 4 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2018-06-30 | 3 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2018-09-30 | 2 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2018-12-31 | 5 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2019-03-31 | 6 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2019-06-30 | 1 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2019-09-30 | 5 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2019-12-31 | 2 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2020-03-31 | 3 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2019-06-30 | 4 | 12M |

Y, agrupando por años, necesito sumar los 4 valores anteriores de la columna 'Valor' respecto a ese año, teniendo algo así:

| Ac | Type | Id | Date | Value | Pe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2017-12-31 | 5 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2018-12-31 | 4+3+2+5 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2019-12-31 | 6+1+5+2 | 12M |
| Debt | Other | DE | 2020-09-30 | 5+2+3+4 | 12M |

Con las siguientes condiciones:

1. Si no es posible sumar 3 fechas anteriores porque no hay 3 filas con fechas anteriores, deja la que ya hay como en el caso de la fila con fecha 2017-12-31 del ejemplo.
2. Si las filas anteriores no son todas del mismo año, suma la columna de valores de esas filas y deja en la columna 'Fecha' la última fecha. Como en el caso de la fila con fecha 2020-09-30 del ejemplo

Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Podrías agregar una demostración de que sos parte del esfuerso por responder tu pregunta por favor? Esto lo podes lograr mostrando un código donde intentes resolver esa problematica. Así, tu pregunta será mejor recibida.

Comment: Listo, ya trabajé en la respuesta. Gracias!

Answer (score -2):

```
df["Value"] = df["Value"].rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum()
rows_to_keep = df["Date"].dt.year.drop_duplicates(keep="last").index
df = df.loc[rows_to_keep]
print(df)
```

Comment: Esto responde a tu duda, o es lo que lograste y no llegaste a avanzar más?

Comment: Responde mi duda. Gracias

Comment: Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega una explicación.

Comment: De nada! Recuerda que Stack Overflow debe de ser tu ultimo recurso. Nunca tires la toalla antes de tiempo.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo tu código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).